# Does Tor bundle discards cookies from a window or only from a session?

Tags: fingerprinting, cookies, metadata

So in firefox privacy mode afaik once you close a private window all cookies and other information related to the sites in that window are deleted independently of any data on the regular firefox window(s) you may have still open. The Tor browser has no private windows but does it discard cookies and other data from a window once it closes? or it only does so if you close the Tor browser altogether and/or ctrl+shit+U for new identity (which also reloads the program)?

What if you ctrl+shit+L for a new circuit? does the data from that specific site/tab get discarded or not?

Answer (score 1):

They're discarded on a per-session basis.

Using the 'New Tor Circuit for this Site' will only cause Tor Browser to use a new circuit for the site, it will not clear any other information. That is what the 'New Identity' option is for, see the [Tor Browser Design and Implementation](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser/design/#new-identity).

**N.B.** On Firefox's *Private Browsing* windows, cookies and other tracking data is absolutely not removed when a *tab* is closed. It is unset when the *window* is closed. This is trivially testable by visiting a site that sets and displays a cookie, closing the *tab* (but keeping the *window* open) and opening a new *tab* on the *Private Browsing* *window* and then checking to see if the cookie is still present.

When tested, it can be seen to be still set. The same is true of Chrom{e,ium}s *Inconito Window*.

Comment: Thing is new identity wipes out all open tabs and windows, is there a middle ground? like a way to implement private windows?

Comment: See my updated answer, the behaviour you describe is not at all what private/incognito windows provide.

Comment: Ok but I asked if private windows could be implemented on TOR somehow

Comment: Tor Browser is *already* in private window mode, so it already functions like one.